# Quick Huffman Tree example

Tags: computer-science, traversal, huffman-code, tree-traversal

I was wondering if it mattered the direction of a huffman tree. Like if the problem was construct a huffman tree for A B C D E and theres a number given for each.

Does it matter if I start from the top and then go down to the bottom in terms of child nodes etc, as long as I label my branches?

Like what if I do left is 1 and right is 0 instead? Is that ok as well?

Because my teacher and many youtube examples explain it in different ways and draw it differently, consequently the same problem would have a different huffman codeword depending on the orientation and how they labeled it.

Comment: It seems like this question should be migrated to cs.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I think you're asking about the construction of the codes as a series of 0's and 1's from the Huffman tree.

If you are asking if you have to start generating the bits from the top of the tree, then yes, otherwise it wouldn't be a prefix code, i.e. uniquely decodable.

If you are asking if you can randomly choose to put the 0 on the left or the right branch, then yes, there are many codes for the same tree, and they all are optimal and they all are uniquely decodable prefix codes.

For transmission efficiency, there is specific choice for assigning the 0's and 1's that can be agreed to by the transmitter and receiver in order to avoid having to include that information in the stream. Look up Canonical Huffman Code.